# PHP - For Loop, split list into 3 separate lists (in order)

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
<?php
        $brandNames = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'brands_list', true );
        if( $brandNames ):
    ?>  
        <ul>
            <?php 
                for( $z = 0; $z < $brandNames; $z++ ):
                $third_count = ceil($brandNames / 3);   

                $brandName =  $brandNames.blah;
            ?>

                <?php echo $brandName;?><br/>

                <?php if($z == $third_count & $brandNames != 1):?>
                    <?php echo "</ul><ul>";?>
                <?php endif;?>

            <?php endfor;?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
```

When it outputs the lists however, it only outputs 2 UL elements, as opposed to 3.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any tips would be appreciated.

It's getting a third of the way through, closing of the UL to create another one, but never creates a third, just a larger second UL.

Comment: `<?php if($z == $third_count && $brandNames != 1):?>` Use flexbox or something to simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Firstly I am counting how many indexes the `$brandNames` array has. I have then changed your conditional statement that is outputting `</ul><ul>`. Firstly I have added 1 to `$z` to get the loop count and then used `%`(modulus) 3 == 0, which decides the loop count by 3 and returns the remainder. If the remainder equals 0, then you know the loop count is a multiple of 3. I have then made sure that the loop count does not equal the total indexes 
 in the `$brandNames` array, so that an additional `</ul><ul>` is not outputted.

```
<?php
    $brandNames = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'brands_list', true );
        $brandCount = count($brandNames);
    if( $brandNames ):
?>
    <ul>
        <?php
          for( $z = 0; $z < $brandNames; $z++ ):
            $brandName =  $brandNames.blah;
        ?>

            <li><?php echo $brandName;?></li>

            <?php if(($z + 1) % 3 == 0 && ($z + 1) != $brandCount): ?>
                <?php echo "</ul><ul>";?>
            <?php endif;?>

        <?php endfor;?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```